# Please don't dress up sales pitches as surveys

Tags: discussion, email, stack-overflow-for-teams

I got this email from SO saying:

> Hi [My actual name \o/],
>
> Thank you for helping us improve Stack Overflow Channels!
>
> We’re researching a new topic and want to invite you to take a short
>   survey. It will take 5-10 minutes if you qualify to complete it.

Willing to help, I did the survey, filling in all kinds of details (including the fact that I *do* work in a large company and *do* have quite some say in the acquisition of these kinds of products/services).

Then halfway, I got about 5 pages of informational slides on the awesomeness of Channels, without any questions in it.

Then I got the question if, after reading this <strike>sales pitch</strike> introductory information, I would be willing to go for Channels. I expected at least some follow up questions in which I could motivate or nuance my 'No', but to my surprise it ended there, indicated I am not the person of interest to the survey, leaving me feeling like I just sent away some door-to-door salesperson.

So my request: Please don't dress up sales pitches as surveys, or more gently put: try to make surveys not look like sales pitches.

Comment: As a workaround, you can probably disable some emails in your email settings: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/<userId>`

Comment: @Cerbrus immediately working URL would be [https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Cherries are the pits!

.... well, that's what I usually get when I've completed something on Survey Monkey Contribute for a chance to spin to win a $100 Amazon gift card. But every time I spin, I end up getting cherries, not bananas (needed to win), I'm starting to think that game is rigged.

Anyway, I digress. The surveys I take (well, mostly, *endure* for a chance to win $100 while passing idle time) are usually from companies trying to answer one of several questions:

- Would you buy [x]?
- How much would you be willing to pay for [x]?
- What name / graphic / packaging makes [x] look the best to you?

... each one of these are essentially contingent on me answering the other in a certain way. If I answer *no* to "Would you buy it?" there's little point in continuing. *But, I get a chance to spin that wheel and curse at cherries no matter what!* and the motivation there is purely extrinsic - I want $100 and something semi-productive to do with my time in the hospital waiting room.

What's subtle here, and more difficult to articulate is that we *understand* your motivation here wasn't to spin to get $100 and those stupid bananas, you just wanted to help us out. If we do surveys similar to this, we'll make certain to give you an option to actually *give* us the feedback you'd reserved some time to compile and provide.

It's a nuance, it's a nicety more than a formality and when you feel comfortable with someone and sort of assume that *they* assume the best in *you* - it can be kinda hard to understand what, exactly, was so upsetting.

Anyway, [Kristina gets it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362813/50049), we get it - and we'll do better, and we're sorry that we weren't more careful with your time and feelings. It wasn't intentional, and sometimes we can be dense in weird places, sorta like memory foam.

Thanks for bringing it up, it sparked an internal discussion about things we need to prioritize when doing surveys like this. And to be clear, we *absolutely* need this data, but we don't need to come off calloused needlessly in the process.

Comment: If the specific subject (pricing of the new product) would have been clear to me in advance, maybe I wouldn't have filled out the survey, and if I would have, I wouldn't have been surprised about it's sudden end. But indeed it's a nuance. I do I understand it wasn't intentional, and that's why I thought it was better to leave some feedback here than to just unsubscribe from mails like this. Thank you, and Kristina, for confirming this.

Comment: Btw, was there a spin at the end? I didn't even know. That certainly wasn't the reason I *endured* this survey.

Comment: For those not well versed in the latest american slang, would you clarify the thing about spinning, cherries, bananas and such? I understand that there is some game where you spin a wheel that has cherries and bananas, but how is it relevant to surveys?

Comment: You seem to link to Kristina's answer at "_Kristina gets it_", but looking at that answer...I'm not sure Kristina gets it.

Comment: You know when Microsoft does something stupid that damages its trust relationship with its customers? And after a big outcry, they eventually reverse it? And they repeat that process over and over again? Why is SO intent on following suit?

Answer (score -22):

I'm one of the researchers working on this survey. It's actually *not* a sales pitch! It's a survey designed to better understand attitudes and perform a [pricing analysis](https://apollonsky.me/how-to-van-westendorp-analysis-excel/) for people who have "purchasing power" at their companies. We're preparing to launch a [new product](https://stackoverflow.com/channels) shortly, and want to make sure we're offering it at a cost and feature set that make sense for the majority of people who may want to use it.

Thanks for flagging this, though. I've added in a line at the beginning of the survey, clarifying that it's not a sales pitch. We're just looking for feedback on our plans. :)

Comment: Clarification is good, but door-to-door salesperson can also say he is not a "door-to-door salesperson" at the beginning of the conversation

Comment: So you're asking about how to best sell your product rather than just trying to sell your product.... That doesn't seem like a big difference to me.

Comment: @xyious That somehow feels worse to me.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well - we're building Channels right now, which is a tool for internal Q&A within a company. Channels, when it launches, will be a paid product for companies and organizations - and we want to make sure that we're charging the right amount for it. To do that, we need to do a pricing analysis. Otherwise, if we charge too much, no one will want to (or be able to) use it. I know that asking questions about price can feel weird, but research like this is really important to do.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand the objection well:  It's misleading at best and rather rude at worst to employ techniques used to qualify sales leads to cut off someone who has volunteered to helped you.  Suggestion: Don't add a line in the beginning denying the problem; fix it by clarifying  in the description exactly who should respond to the survey.  Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been more transparent and less likely to be received poorly if the invitation had said up front that the survey was part of a market analysis?  It might be that fewer people would respond, but part of the problem is that some people feel like they've been suckered into responding.

Comment: @KristinaLustig, in a completely non-argumentative way. Is there any public  market research for the adoption rate of such a product? As in, what research was done that stated this would be a successful product? I'd be interested in why this is being pushed from SO. You've mentioned [why](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/11/09/why-channels/), but this product just seems so "pushy" for some reason

Comment: @MattR We don't have any research data to share, but we've been inundated with requests for a product like this for years. There's definitely a desire for it and a need for it! Can you tell me a bit more about how it feels pushy? That's definitely not a feeling we want to engender.

Comment: eh, I'm a young guy with the monetary personality of a grandpa and who ["know what he's about, son"](https://youtu.be/9baLJrPaQgM) so anything that charges me anything for something I can do for free rubs me the wrong way. As for a real example, I work with *highly* sensitive data and I've always been able to mock-up sample data for SO. My co-workers and I seem to get along fine without Channels.

Comment: We've used email, sending code files, and SO links to solve issues. So 1) I might just be a "grumpy non-customer" and I should be ignored and 2) should absolutely be ignored if the data says otherwise. that's why I was curious about the study to see if I was wrong about the perceived need. Especially when it comes to the size of companies. As telecommuting becomes more and more popular, *maybe* a product like this solves the issue? These are the types of syndicated data analyses I was curious about :)

Comment: @MattR What you've said makes sense for sure! I don't think that Channels is the right tool for every company or group (it sounds like y'all have a good system in place), but there are definitely a lot of people who are looking for a way to handle internal Q&A - not just coding questions but even best practices and "where do I find" type stuff - in a way that's straightforward and long-term sustainable. Thanks for your thoughts. :)